# Google Apps Activity API: 403

Tags: api, google-api, google-oauth

I am integrating a web application with the [Google  Apps Activity API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/v1/reference/activities/list) and I keep getting the same JSON response when trying out the api on the google developer website

```
`{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
 }
}`
```

Does anyone know how to get this returning activity data? I can not find anyone online using this API. It seems really useful but no one is using it.

Updated Question:

I have a "Google Apps Unlimited" account for testing as well. I can access other APIs such as the "Google Drive API" just fine. But when it comes to this API, it always retirns this message. I've also activated the "Google Apps Activity API" in my Developer Console. It says "ON" with a 10,000,000 request limit. I also have billing enabled for the project. I have also setup the correct keys. I use Oauth2. I also tried an API key. They give the same result. 403... I have already read all the other stackoverflow posts. No one else seems to be using this API.

Comment: So what about this? https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#activatingapis

Comment: @SiKing this is the Google Playground. Google's own site for testing their APIS. presumably, they've activated this on their own playground project. But I will update my question to say that I have also tried this on my business account and it does the same thing even with The API activated. I have a "Google Apps Unlimited" account. I can access other APIs such as the "Google Drive API" just fine.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue? Same thing is happening within our Google Apps environment as well as in the playground. Other APIs are working fine.

Comment: For the Apps Activity API, make sure you provide the Root drive ancestor ID, as well as the source parameters: Source = drive.google.com. You can get the root Drive ID by calling Drive API's About resource.

Answer (score 0):

After talking to Google Tech Support, it seems this was a google issue. It's now working again. The API was broken for a bit.